# Planning Facebook Local Currency, changes

Tags: facebook

I have a series of games, each run by game administrators.  The administrators set pricing of "items" within each game.  All items are in multiples of $1 USD, but items change regularly.

Currently purchases are done in a shopping cart, totaled, and sent to FB with the total value only.

I know I'm cutting it close, time wise, on these changes.

I do not understand all my options yet.  Do I need to define a single in-game currency that costs $1, then make all purchases cost based on a multiple of that item?  (A $50 purchase that may be a combination of two or three in-game items, costs 50 of whatever my in-game "currency" item is?)

This seems like a pain, compared to saying "They are making a $39 purchase, please handle"

Please help me understand my options.

Thank you!

Comment: You set your price for whatever you want to sell in any of the local currencies offered, and Facebook handles conversion of the amount to the local currency of the user. Start with the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/local-currency-payments/

Comment: I need to make it dynamic enough for when the game administrators made sudden price changes, or add new items for sale.  From what I was reading, I needed to pre-define everything.  This could easily be my own lack of understanding.

Comment: You can either define your own virtual currency within your app, or use in-app items. And you can price them statically or dynamically at time of purchase. You should really take the time to go through the documentation thoroughly to get a better understanding of the whole new Local Currency Payments system and how it works.

Comment: What I'm not seeing, is a way to do dynamic in-app items.  I can see you can set dynamic pricing on items, but all items must be defined ahead of time.  Is this correct?